# Access data from a function [React Native]

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, return-value

I am trying to get the original size image from a url and display the image based on its ratio. I used `Image.getSize()` to do the job.

This is what I've done so far :

```
function displayimgThumb(file_url){
  var win         = Dimensions.get('window');
  var ratio       = 0
  var imgWidth    = 0;
  var imgHeight   = 0;

  Image.getSize(file_url, (width, height) => {
    ratio     = win.width / width;
    imgWidth  = win.width;
    imgHeight = height * ratio;
  });

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <FastImage
        style={{
          width: imgWidth,
          height: imgHeight
        }}
        source={{
            uri: file_url,
            priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

See the `Image.getSize()`, I can get the width and height of the image but I am unable to access the data from outside. Means I cannot get the width and height set in `<FastImage />` style as the data cannot be accessed.

How should I pass it through there? For some reason, I am unable to use `setState()` cause I'm using a function from a different separated file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @NickParsons I'm not a 100% sure, but I think awaitng the response will not work in this case, because this would stall the component output, since we have a JSX output returned by this method.
So it is better to show something in the meantime until it is finished and just rerender as soon, as the getSize function has returned something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is, that Image.getSize is an async function, that will finish, after you have return your content.
Since `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` are just normal variables, that will not trigger a rerender on change.

The way to go here would either be to put `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` into the state of this function.

With a class component you can just use `this.setState({ imgHeight: ..., imgWidht: ...});`.
With a functional component, you would need to use the `stateHook`.

Here is an example for a class component.

```
    import React from 'react';
    ...

    class MyComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor (props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                imgWidth: null,
                imgHeight: null,
                ratio: null,
            };
        }

        function displayimgThumb (file_url) {
            // here you are getting the image dimensions from state again.
            const { imgWidth, imgHeight, ratio } = this.state;
            var win       = Dimensions.get('window');

            // just checking, we actually have dimensions (image is loaded, to prevent wrong rendering)
            // only call "Image.getSize" when we don't have a size yet - if you go this way it is more performant, but you might to have to add a special case for screen size changes
            if (imgWidth === null) { 
               Image.getSize(file_url, (width, height) => {
                   ratio     = win.width / width;

                   // here you set the state as soon as you have the image size and thereby trigger a rerender of the whole component, but this time with image dimensions you know
                   this.setState({
                       imgWidth: win.width,
                       imgHeight: (height * ratio),
                       ratio,
                   });
               });

               return (
                  <View>
                     // JUST SHOW SOMETHING UNTIL THE IMAGE SIZE HAS LOADED (which usually doesn't take very long)
                     // or return null here, to show nothing until that happens
                  </View>
               );
            }

            return (
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <FastImage
                        style={{
                            width: imgWidth,
                            height: imgHeight
                        }}
                        source={{
                            uri: file_url,
                            priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
                        }}
                        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }

        function render() {
            return (
                <>
                    {this.displayimgThumb}
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```